# #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: mysql

can anyone see why I'm getting the error commands out of sync.  Most of this query works in MSSQL, but I've tried to modify it to work in MySQL.

```
select pl.playerID, ( IFNull((select SUM(rsAmount) + SUM(rsOtherWinningsValue) from tn_results     where playerID=pl.playerID and includedInMoneyList=1) , 0)
 + pl.baseMoney) as totalMoney, pl.firstName, pl.lastName, pl.city, pl.state, pl.baseMoney, 
( SELECT count(*) 
 FROM tn_participants tp INNER JOIN 
tournament tn ON tn.tourneyID = tp.tourneyID LEFT OUTER JOIN 
registered_player rp ON rp.playerID = tp.playerID 
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) 
 FROM tn_participants tp INNER JOIN 
tournament tn ON tn.tourneyID = tp.tourneyID RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
registered_player rp ON rp.playerID = tp.playerID
WHERE tp.playerID = pl.playerID and tn.firstDay >'12/31/(Year(NOW)-1)') 
as moneyList from registered_player pl 
where pl.divisionId=2
order by totalMoney DESC
```

Comment: This sounds like it may be a programming or tooling problem - not an SQL problem. How are you executing the query?

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin